# Camera through Android Emulator

Tags: android, camera

I am developing few multimedia solution, for same I am dealing with Camera, i Have webcam but there are some limitations in android so that I cannot use it in emulator.

Now my question is, how android play sound, I could hear mp3 files from android emulator, how speaker is accessed through Android ?

Please do the needful,

Answer (score 2):

See following links to get live previow on android emulator:

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/09/live-camera-preview-in-android-emulator.html

http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source